# No such DSL method 'httpRequest' found among steps

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to request info from A REST API in my Jenkins pipeline, I have tried this code in various ways, but I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'httpRequest' found among steps
```

I am beginning to think that it has something to do with my syntax, but I cannot figure out what.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
stage('Check Change No'){
    steps{
        script{
                def response = httpRequest contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                        httpMode: 'GET',
                        validResponseCodes: '100:499',
                        url: "http://info-service-helm-chart-microservice-bin-deploy.apps.c01u.paas.mynet.com/v3/isDeployAlloved/123456"        
                echo response.status.toString()
                if(response.status.toString() != "200"){
                    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
                    def responseObject = jsonSlurper.parseText(response.getContent())
                    String errorMsg = responseObject.errors[0]    
                    println "ERROR:"+ errorMsg
                }
                else{
                    println "ALL OK!!!. Change Approved."
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I managed to figure it out, the solution is to install the jenkins plugin "HTTP requests" it was not installed on the jenkins instance i worked on.